# SQL Group by Count String occurance

Tags: sql

I am wanting to count the occurrences of a specific string in SQL.
I have UserID's which are unique and each user can carry out an "action". I've tried a few things but still cannot get it to work.

So these actions can be "throw" "pickup" "craft"

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(action)
FROM `playeractions`
GROUP BY action;
```

| userid | COUNT(action) |
| --- | --- |
| 7656119 | 129 |
| 76561194 | 4 |

Expected results required

| userid | throw | pickup | craft |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7656119 | 29 | 100 | 0 |
| 76561194 | 2 | 2 | 0 |

Existing data of the table

| userid | action |
| --- | --- |
| 7656119 | throw |
| 76561194 | pickup |
| 76561194 | pickup |
| 76561194 | throw |

Comment: we need table structure and sample data

Comment: Your probably want to do `GROUP BY userid`, and not by action, that's at least what most tutorials say you should do when you need a lit of userid's with a count.

Comment: Updated table data, thank you. I can do this within PHP and loop through it but feel it will be much more efficient to query the database and deal with the data received.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The accepted answer is product specific, and wont work on most dbms's.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simple privot the data

```
SELECT
    userid,
    SUM(action = 'throw') as 'throw',
    SUM(action = 'pickup') as 'pickup',
    SUM(action = 'craft') as 'craft'
FROM table1
GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: Great stuff! That has done the trick. I was unaware of SUM within queries so I have learnt something for the future. Have a blessed weekend sir.

Answer (score 2):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT userid, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN action = 'throw' THEN 1 END) AS throw,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN action = 'pickup' THEN 1 END) AS pickup,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN action = 'craft' THEN 1 END) AS craft
FROM playeractions 
GROUP BY userid;
```

Depending on the database that you use the code may be simplified.

Comment: Thank you :) This will work too, @nbk got in just a few seconds before but I appreciate your time.